# Can't modify AWS PostgreSQL RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I was trying to modify "DB parameter group" in my instance. But I was not able to finish modifying it because of this little gem:

[image: Impossible validation]

As you can see Max value is smaller than Min value.

100 GiB - value I entered some time ago in previous modifications.

My current "Allocated storage" is 35 GiB.

[image: Current allocated storage]

For some reason I can't change it now because input field is disabled.

In general, I can't modify this instance at all because every time validation fails on "Maximum storage threshold".

How can I modify this instance now? Is this a bug with UI? Or is instance executing some background tasks?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in the UI. I suggest you should contact AWS support about this and if you cannot, then I suggest you create a new DB instance from a snapshot and see if that one behaves normally. You could also create a slave (read replica) and if the slave is not broken too, then promote the slave to master.

Comment: I checked my RDS instance, several hours later and the problem was gone. I suspect instance, was going through some hidden process. Still, I will report this bug to AWS support, because UI behavior is a joke and there were no messages describing hidden processes.